# subsonic 3.0.0.3 for multiple primary keys table

Tags: subsonic

When I use ActiveRecord template,that can't generator correct primary key for multiple primary keys table.
I can't update that table.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your table has Composite Primary Keys (comprised of more than one field in that table), then SubSonic doesn't support it - see [Update a primary key value using SubSonic 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025503/update-a-primary-key-value-using-subsonic-2-2)