# Subsonic updates multiple rows instead of 1?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, subsonic, subsonic3

Subsonic 3.0 is updating multiple rows instead of just the one it's supposed to

```
 DB Table is defined as follows -
 Col1 int NOT NULL
 Col2 Text NOT NULL
 Col3 INT NOT NULL
 ColX NTEXT
 COLY NTEXT

 Primary Key = Col1 + Col2 + Col3
 ....
```

the select expr is as follows

```
 myTable a = myTable.SingleOrDefault( x => x.Col1 = 1 && x.Col2 = 'abc' && x.Col3 = 9 );
 if ( a == null )
 {
     // not relevant in this case !
 }

 .... some code 
 a.ColX = myString1;

 a.Update();
```

@ this point all the rows where Col1 = 1 are set to myString1

env -  db is sql 2008 R2 Express, .net 3.5, c#

Comment: `x => x.Col1 = 1 && x.Col2 = 'abc' && x.Col3 = 9` is not valid (compilable) C#.  Presumably you mean `==`.

Comment: If your Subsonic query returns >1 record for that primary key, then of course an update on that primary key is going to update every record with that key.  The .SingleOrDefault is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubSonic does not appear to support composite primary keys - you'll have to create a surrogate key to do what you want.

See also: [SubSonic 3 and multiple PK columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183595/subsonic-3-and-multiple-pk-columns/1185070#1185070)

Comment: doh ! i suppose it helps to read the feature set before using a product :) thanks !